# Change the next rows values in the pandas group if value of a row is a specific number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset, consisting of users and the date of their purchases:

```
user_id | purchase_date
u1      | 2020-06-01
u1      | 2020-07-01
u1      | 2020-08-01
u1      | 2020-09-01
u2      | 2020-06-01
u2      | 2020-08-01
u2      | 2020-08-01
u2      | 2020-09-01
u3      | 2020-06-01
u3      | 2020-07-01
```

I've added two other columns to the dataset, so it has become:

```
user_id | purchase_date | previous_purchase | months_from_previous_purchase
u1      | 2020-06-01    | NaT               | NaN
u1      | 2020-07-01    | 2020-06-01        | 1
u1      | 2020-08-01    | 2020-07-01        | 1
u1      | 2020-09-01    | 2020-08-01        | 1
u2      | 2020-06-01    | NaT               | NaN
u2      | 2020-08-01    | 2020-06-01        | 2
u2      | 2020-08-01    | 2020-08-01        | 0
u2      | 2020-09-01    | 2020-08-01        | 1
u3      | 2020-06-01    | NaT               | NaN
u3      | 2020-07-01    | 2020-06-01        | 1
```

Now I want to add a new column (`drop`), I want to fill it with:

- 0: if the current and all previous rows of `months_from_previous_purchase` for the current `user_id` is 0, 1, or NaN
- 1: otherwise

So the final dataset should be like the following:

```
user_id | purchase_date | previous_purchase | months_from_previous_purchase | drop
u1      | 2020-06-01    | NaT               | NaN                           | 0
u1      | 2020-07-01    | 2020-06-01        | 1                             | 0
u1      | 2020-08-01    | 2020-07-01        | 1                             | 0
u1      | 2020-09-01    | 2020-08-01        | 1                             | 0
u2      | 2020-06-01    | NaT               | NaN                           | 0
u2      | 2020-08-01    | 2020-06-01        | 2                             | 1
u2      | 2020-08-01    | 2020-08-01        | 0                             | 1
u2      | 2020-09-01    | 2020-08-01        | 1                             | 1
u3      | 2020-06-01    | NaT               | NaN                           | 0
u3      | 2020-07-01    | 2020-06-01        | 1                             | 0
```

The last two rows of user `u2` have got 1, because we've seen a value more than 1 for `months_from_previous_purchase` for user `u2`, so all next value of `drop` for this user should be 1.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve it with this trick:

```py
df["drop"] = df["months_from_previous_purchase"].apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x > 1 else 0
)
df["drop"] = df.groupby("user_id").agg(drop=("drop", "cumsum"))
df["drop"] = df["drop"].apply(
    lambda x: 1 if x >= 1 else 0
)
```

The result is exactly as wanted in the question. Does anybody have a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df['drop'] = df['months_from_previous_purchase'].apply(lambda x: int(not (x in [0, 1] or pd.isna(x)))).cumsum(axis=0)
print(df)

...
       months_from_previous_purchase  drop  
    0                            NaN     0  
    1                            1.0     0  
    2                            1.0     0  
    3                            1.0     0  
    4                            NaN     0  
    5                            2.0     1  
    6                            0.0     1  
    7                            1.0     1
```

Comment: It doesn't work when you have another user after u2. I updated my example dataset and added a u3. The value for u3 should be 0. @antoine

Comment: Your answer hasn't considered the grouping of users.